# Que puedo hacer para que se guarde el estado de un option en angular

Tags: angular

**Descripción del problema**: tengo una aplicación en angular la cuan es un panel de usuarios que se registran de un sitio web la función del panel es cambiar los estados de cada usuario según vayan pagando.

**la solución que necesito**: necesito poder guardar el estado cuando se selecciona uno u otra opción sin importar que se refresque la pagina

comparto todo mi ts:

```
export class OrdenesComponent implements OnInit {
  ListOfOrders: ordenInterce[];

  OrdenDelete: ordenInterce;

  estados = [
    {
      id: 'paid',
      label: 'Pagado',
    },
    {
      id: 'toPay',
      label: 'Por pagar',
    },
  ];


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getListOfOrders();
  }


  recargarDespuesDeSubirArchivo(){
    this.getListOfOrders();
  }
  constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private OrdenesService: OrdenesService
  ) {}

  openDetallePoliza(content: any): void {
    this.modalService.open(content, {
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title',
      /*windowClass: 'confirmacionUsuariosModal',*/
    });
  }

  getListOfOrders = async () => {
    try {
      this.ListOfOrders = await this.OrdenesService.adminListOfOrders();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } 
  };

  openModalEliminarOrden = (content, OrdenDelete: ordenInterce) => {
    this.OrdenDelete = OrdenDelete;
    this.modalService.open(content, {
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title',
      /*windowClass: 'confirmacionUsuariosModal',*/
    });
  };

  deleteOrden = () => {
    this.OrdenesService.deleteOrder(this.OrdenDelete.orderId).then(() => {
      this.modalService.dismissAll();
      Swal.fire(
        'Orden Eliminada',
        'La orden fue eliminada correctamente',
        'success'
      );
      this.getListOfOrders();
    });
  };
}
```

esto esta en el component.html aqui solo coloque la parte de la tabla donde necesito el cambio de los estados que son pagado y por pagar:

```
         <div class="select-custom-forms">
              <select [(ngModel)]="poliza.status">
                <option *ngFor="let estado of estados" 
                   [value]="estado.id">
                  {{ estado.label }}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

adjunto imagen de lo que tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto esta imagen para mas detalle es un panel de administración de usuarios no un registro de usuarios necesito que cuando se cambie el estado se mantenga:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El codigo de mi solucion en github[codigo en github](https://github.com/nestdanchia/selectChange.git)
que corresponde a tu pregunta anterior con respecto a un solo select consultabas como lograr que el valor seleccionado se mantenga luego de cambiar de ruta o al refrescar la pagina
Ahora modificaste la pregunta y mostras una foto de una tabla sin subir el codigo que usas  no es adecuado solo subir imagenes para que te puedan responder ya que si fuera Angular material se podria usar openedChange: EventEmitter

> Con el siguiente codigo podes obtener el valor asignarlo guardarlo por ejemplo en localStorage para un select
> asi mantiene el valor tanto al cambiar de ruta como al refrescar la pagina
> Los Formularios Reactivos son de mucha utilidad podes leer algo de teoría de ellos y un ejemplo con select no es la opción que usaste ni tampoco la que repondi pero creo es la mejor opción  ya que si fuera una tabla de angular material se podria usar por ejemplo openedChange: EventEmitter pero depende todo del codigo que usas
> [teoria formularios reactivos](https://academia-binaria.com/formularios-reactivos-con-Angular/)
> y un ejemplo de uso de select con formularios reactivos
> [ejemplo con select de formularios reactivos](https://www.positronx.io/angular-7-select-dropdown-examples-with-reactive-forms/)
> como se guarda el localStorage agregue un boton para eliminar el item estado del mismo cuando sea necesario

```js
//ts
 estado!:string;
selectedValue!:string;
ngOnInit() {
this.selectedValue=localStorage.getItem('estado') || 'ESTADO';
 }

onChange(event: Event) {
    let estado = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    localStorage.setItem('estado', this.estado);
     this.selectedValue=localStorage.getItem('estado') || 'ESTADO';
console.log('this.selectedValue',this.selectedValue,localStorage.getItem('estado'))
   
  }
  
   removeItemStorage(key: string) {
localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
```

```html
<div class="select-custom-forms">
    <select (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" >
     
      <option *ngFor="let estado of estados" [value]="estado.id">
        {{ estado.label }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  

<h1> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="removeItemStorage('estado')">
  Remove estado  local storage
  </button></h1>
```

La imagen es solo para que el que consulto vea donde se guardan las variables en LocalStorage el codigo esta completo en la respuesta no es nuevo codigo el de la imagen

[image: La imagen es solo para que el que consulta vea donde ver las variables definidas en el localstorage]

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero sigue sin guardarse, en la consola me arroja que guarda un undefined

Comment: Modificaste tu codigo de acuerdo al codigo que publique porque en el que publicas no podes acceder con el select de la forma en que lo haces probe el codigo que publique y da el resultado requerido pero si no modifixas por ejemplo a <select (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" > y otras modificaciones no podras capturar el valor saludos

Comment: en localstorage se guardara la variable de acuerdo a la imagen que agregue

Comment: @nestdan Hola!, las aportaciones con imágenes son poco claras y/o confusas. Para realizar un ejemplo más funcional para todos puedes usar servicios como [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com).

Comment: de esta manera tengo el html:                 <div class="select-custom-forms">
                  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="onChange($event)">
                    <option *ngFor="let estado of estados" [value]="estado.id">
                      {{ estado.label }}
                    </option>
                  </select>
                </div>

Comment: javier sin (change)="onChange($event)" no vas a poder asignar valores al localstorage para asi poder cambiar de ruta y que se guarde la seleccion la imagen la subi psolo para que veas donde buscar las variables definidas en localstorage.Aunque el codigo esta completo y se puede pegar y copiar en cualquier proyecto Angular para verificarlo lo subo a github y te copio el enlace

Comment: Legna aclare el porque de la imagen en la respuesta Javier te subo la respuesta a github

Comment: lo agrege a un borrador no tengo tiempo de crear otro proyecto y subirlo  el evento esta en linea de codigo 369 del componente rxjs.component,ts  y el templete en rxjs.component.html  https://github.com/nestdanchia/select/blob/main/src/app/rxjs/rxjs.component.ts

Comment: fijate que con ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedValue=localStorage.getItem('estado') || 'default-token';
  } obtenemos valor del localstorage y en el metodo onChange(event: Event){ seteamos el valor del local storage de acuerdo al valor seleccionado}de esa forma se almacena ese valor aunque cambies de ruta o refresques la pagina

Comment: gracias nestdan por la respuesta, ahora me surge el problema que al cambiar 1 se cambian todos modifique mi pregunta agregue una imagen mas clara del panel, hay manera de que sean individuales?

Comment: si seguis al proyecto que subi no tendrias problemas pensalo https://github.com/nestdanchia/selectChange.git